# Mongodb primary key on ASP.NET Core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project, currently testing CRUD, the database is using Mongodb. After watching the tutorial to try to do it once, I found that the ID in the database and the ID in the category I set each generated a set of IDs, from the DB structure, the ID I set in the type is treated as general data.

The main purpose may be the index used when calling the database of web pages (my guess), so would you like to ask, is it possible that these two sets of IDs will be integrated into one?

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: There was a few way to map the `_id` field, it may use annotation `BsonElement`, `BsonId`, `ConventionPack`, `ConventionRegistry`, `NamedIdMemberConvention`,... the implementation would be vary, so GG still your best friend :)

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. I have update this way. Is it right?

Comment: You got it... consider using `BsonElement` if its not auto mapped with `_id` and that `Id` won't be null anyway (and why not we use `ObjectId` datatype ?)

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg.Because when I use ObjectID datatype, it will be error like photo3

Comment: `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()` is the right tool for the job

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg.Yes, it can work now. Thanks!!